# .NET on Windows to Mono on Ubuntu

Tags: .net, mono

I am looking at a possibility to change my ASP.NET 2.0 application to the Mono framework. I have used the Mono Migration Analyzer tool and it does detect some P/Invoke and interop dependencies.

For example:

1) We use Excel interops and on Linux we are looking to use StarOffice/OpenOffice instead. Is there an easy way of substituting Excel with StarOffice? (I know it sounds bizarre, but I just don't want to miss out in case anyone has done it already.)

2) LDAP authentication: What could be the best alternative in Ubuntu (or an other flavour of Linux)?

3) Is there an Ajax framework for Mono? Preferably with similar controls as [Atlas](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ASP.NET_AJAX)?

I hope I am not too ambitious here..

Comment: "I hope I am not too ambitious here.." - If it weren't for ambition, we would still be carrying clubs - or worse, crawling in mud.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1) Yes, there is a Mono interop layer for OpenOffice. It's not very friendly, but it works.

2) If you just want to use LDAP from your app, there's a Novell.Directory.Ldap library shipped with Mono, and probably others available.

3) Mono includes ASP.NET AJAX. There are other libraries available such as Gaia AJAX.

Comment: I am looking at moving to Mono on Ubuntu, so Interops would go for a toss. I am looking for alternatives to Interops in Linux i.e. How would I create an openoffice scalc object in Linux?

Comment: The OpenOffice interop layer also works with .NET on Windows, and you can find several articles online.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, found something for LDAP alternative in Linux - http://www.openldap.org/' alt="OpenLDAP">OpenLDAP.
Would be helpful if someone could share the experiences of migrating roles and users from Windows Active Directory to OpenLDAP. And if anyone has used OpenLDAP in ASP.NET.